# How Composer api works internally

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I am curious to know, how composer API interacts internally with fabric up to committing the data in the blockchain.

Consider a scenario, where I built an application using Composer and deploy the .bna into fabric runtime.

I submit a transactions via composer REST server. 
Need to know

1) how composer API is linked to fabric API. 
2) How Composer will make use of endorsing, committing and order peer.
3) How transaction is converted into Block and committed to the ledger.

Answer (score 0):

you can read more in the README here (scroll down) -> https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/blob/master/packages/composer-runtime/README.md

For example, it describes the runtime and all its constituent components such as the engine, and its services. You can use this README as a navigation point and then explore the source(s) as you wish.

Comment: I feel we need more documentation to understand it. Could you please help me in connecting with them. I can contribute as an article, which will be helpful for others as well

Comment: Composer uses the fabric node-sdk to communicate with a fabric. TP functions are executed through the composer runtime which is chaincode that interfaces to the fabric shim api's. The fabric itself controls endorsement, ordering and concensus as well as creating the blocks for the ledger, it is transparent to composer. If you want to understand hyperledger fabric more, there is more information on their documentation website http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release/